# How to map a route for a URL variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to validate that at least one input on a webpage has data in it. The page is named `CustomValidator.cshtml`, I have written code to validate this both server and client-side. The issue I'm having is that when I click the `submit` button it adds a variable `?Length=19` so when submit is clicked the URL changes from `http://localhost:63199/Home/CustomValidator` to `http://localhost:63199/Home/CustomValidator?Length=19`.

My question is how would I configure RouteConfig.cs to account for this added variable and not cause a 404 error when the submit button is clicked?

here is RouteConfig.cs :

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Validator",
            url: "{controller}/CustomValidator/{Length}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "CustomValidator"}
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        
    }
}
```

With the above configuration for the `Validator` route when the submit button is clicked the URL changes to `*http://localhost:63199/Home/CustomValidator/19`

Thanks in advance for any help as I am a newbie to ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Validator",
    url: "{controller}/CustomValidator/{Length}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "CustomValidator", Length= UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```

Will work for both `/Home/CustomValidator/19` and `/Home/CustomValidator?Length=19`